# Problem Setting up a build in azure devops for mvc appliaction(The type or namespace name 'mvc' could not be found)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-devops, yaml, visual-studio-2019, devops

I have a mvc3 application in. net framework 4.7.2.
This is a solution that was upgraded from mvc2 and build with out issue in visual studio 2019.
I do not have any nuget package.
My source code is in git azure devops.
I try to create a asp.net build in azure devops and I receive the following errors

1. List item Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2. Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3. Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UrlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Please note I have system.web.mvc and system.web.webpages added to my references in MVC project and it complies ok in Visual Studio 2019.

here is content of my **yml** file:

[image]

Comment: Would you please [mark your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)? This will make it easier for people who have the same question to find answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first restore NuGet packages so please enable these steps:

```yaml
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
```

Comment: I don't think i need to restore any nuget package, my MVC project does not have any package folder and pacakge.config as this was an upgrade from MVC2 application However I gave your suggestion a try and removed those 2 lines of comments still the same error.

Comment: Do you have the same on Microsoft host agents?

Comment: i added package.config and used  Package Manager Console Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 3.0.50813.1. I uncommented the nuget task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)' it still does not work?!! Does the number matter which comes after @ sign? - task: NuGetToolInstaller@0 . for example 0 or 1?

Comment: @user464291 did you try to compile it on Microsoft Host agent. Please change `pool: "Default"` to `pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'`

Comment: Thank u for the help i figured out the issue plz see the below post for the answer

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue . I did not have any package.config in my solution . I added that and installed asp.net MVC package and it works now